# How to hide and abstract Java property files?

Tags: java, maven, properties

My application uses a number of properties files to store passwords, URL's and other application data. I would like to abstract the details of these files from the source code. What are the best practices for doing so?

I'm considering creating a plugin in Maven which depending on the environment the application is deployed to will pull down a certain set of properties from say a database however this seems like a lot of work to achieve this. Any suggestions would be welcome. The main goal is to remove sensitive data from the code base.

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use [Maven filtering](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/filter.html) and profiles to do this. In my properties files I just use placeholders like `database.password=${database.password}` then I create a profile in my local maven settings that has the `database.password` property set similar to

```
<profiles>
    <profile>
      <id>development</id>
      <properties>
        <database.password>MySuperSecretPassword</database.password>
      </properties>
    </profile>
<profiles>
```

so when I run `mvn install -P development` it swaps the placeholder with my password.
You can find a more [detailed example here](http://www.manydesigns.com/en/portofino/portofino3/tutorials/using-maven-profiles-and-resource-filtering), although it appears he keeps his profiles in the pom.xml rather than his local maven settings file (possibly for simplicity)

Comment: I admit to doing this same thing, but it must be mentioned that we really haven't plugged any security holes with this approach.  Your final artefact (jar/war/ear) will contain the *MySuperSecretPassword* in plaintext embedded in one or more of your filtered properties files.If you can live with that then this approach works.Ideally it would be nice to filter and encrypt and then your application could decrypt the property when it need consume it (I do not know of such a solution as of writing this).

Comment: I find the reason I'd do this is to just remove the plaintext passwords from a code base (a SVN server hosting multiple team's projects). If you're worried about people extracting passwords from your deployed artefacts then the bigger security question is why are people who you don't trust able to access your deployed artefacts?

I'm happy using this approach because I use it to deploy WARs to a server with access controls and I know the people who'd be able see the properties already know them.